# Rewards instead of penalty in optaplanner

Tags: drools, optaplanner

So I have lectures and time periods and some lectures **need** to be taught in a specific time period. How do i do that?

Does `scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 10);` solve this as a hard constraint? Does the value of positive 10 ensure the constraint of courses being in a specific time period?

I'm aware of the Penalty pattern but I don't want to make **a lot** of `CoursePeriodPenalty` objects. Ideally, i'd like to only have one `CoursePeriodReward` object to say that `CS101` should be in time period `9:00-10:00`

Comment: Wouldn't some facts describing the required assignments and inserted into WM in the way Optaplanner produces the facts of the solution take care of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locking them with **Immovable planning entities** won't work as I suspect you still want OptaPlanner to decide the room for you - and currently optaplanner only supports MovableSelectionFilter per entity, not per variable (vote for the open jira for that).

A **positive hard constraint** would definitely work. Your score will be harder to interpret for your users though, for example a solution with a hard score of 0 won't be feasible (either it didn't get that +10 hard points or it lost 10 hard points somewhere else).

Or you could add a **new negative hard constraint** type that says if `!= desiredTimeslot` then loose 10 points.